# Plotting eigenvalues in R?

Tags: r, pca, eigenvalue

I was trying to visualize eigenvalues with my data for PCA using `prcomp()`, but could not get the Scree plot, which I had before, instead got some errors.

This is my code:

```
fviz_eig(res.pca)

Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.11 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required.
```

I updated my library, installed also packages "scales" but still it was not working.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example—it's really hard to help with no data, no output, and no information on what packages you're using. Since we can't run your code, it's also unclear where the scree plot would come from

Comment: Update your [tag:rlang] package. The installed version of [tag:rlang] is **0.4.11**, however, the requirement is **>= 1.0.0**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
I updated my rlang, but still it is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing tha thte error message is now different but you have not offered the text of it so we cannot apply any logic to the phrase "not working".

Answer (score 0):

Update your [rlang](/questions/tagged/rlang) package. The installed version of [rlang](/questions/tagged/rlang) is **0.4.11**, however, the requirement is **>= 1.0.0**. You may reinstall [rlang](/questions/tagged/rlang) by:

```
install.packages("rlang")
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
I updated my rlang, but still it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
I updated my rlang, but still it is not working.